# Coax or STP input to the Deserializer

Tags: voltage, current, serial, coax, deserialiser

I have this [MAX9278](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9278-MAX9282.pdf) deserializer.

I am planning to give Shielded Twisted Pair (STP) input to the IN+ and IN- pins of the deserializer instead of COAX input.

Can someone help me to let me know what pins or pin configurations I need to change in the deserializer pin out or what I need to take care incase I am planning to give STP input instead of COAX input?

What would be address in the case of STP input?

I am unable to find clear information in the datasheet regarding this.
Please do help.

Comment: +IN and -IN can be used single-ended or differentially and that means using coax or STP. Is there something in your head that makes you think you have to define some register for this to work correctly?

Comment: I think the CX/TP needs to be changed when we use COAX or Twisted as that;s what the name of pin suggests I think.. (For ex. If I use COAX, the CX/TP should be pulled high and when I use STP, the CX/TP should be pulled Low).The previous example is what I think. But is that not the case? So, are you mentioning that I can use either inputs COAX or STP without the need for changing any other pins?

Comment: Seems like table 10 defines this.

Comment: So, I should connect CX/TP to ground, If I connect the STP inputs to the IN+ / IN- pins of deserializer? And what if I connect COAX input to those pins?

Comment: I'd contact Maxim over this. I'm at my limit of understanding on this chip.

Comment: OK thank you for help